# oracle: INSERT where a=b

Tags: oracle, insert

I need to insert values into table only when condition is true.

I try to do smth like this:

```
select (case when a = b  
 then insert into tbl values (1, 1) end) 
            from dual;
```

But it doesnt work:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this way:-

```
INSERT INTO tbl 
  (column1, column2) 
VALUES( 
  (SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE a=b), 
  (SELECT column2 FROM table2 WHERE a=b)
)
```

### UPDATED:

```
INSERT INTO tbl 
  (column1, column2) 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM dual WHERE a=b
```

Comment: @user2111173: Try the other way too